# episerver 4 - Adding form tag in the editor

Tags: episerver

Im currently working with an old version of EPiServer. 
In the editor I need to add html like this:

```
<FORM method=get name=name action=http://somesite.html target=_blank>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=5 width=400>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT name=keywords maxLength=50 size=30><INPUT value=Search type=submit> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></FORM>
```

This does not work and I think it is because there will be two form tags on the page.
Any ideas?

Edit: More specific: The form tag is of course nested.

This works

```
<p><input id="someId" type="text" /> 
<input onclick="window.open('http://somesite.html'+document.getElementById('someId').value)" type="button" value="Search" /></p>
```

Case closed.....

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to add something in the Editor that isn't supported from the editor toolbar.

But since you are able to save the HTML the answer is in your templates. Most likely your masterpage has a big ASP.NET server FORM enclosing most of the BODY.

Answer (score 0):

All webforms-based pages must have an enclosing form tag which is runat="server" (as stated in previous answers).

Back in the EPiServer 4 days we once did an ugly hack in adding a second form after the ASP.NET runat="server" form and then repositioned it with CSS. This second form cannot contain any asp.net controls that are runat="server".